# Flutter Revenuecat product prices always on USD

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

I'm using Revenuecat for in-app payment v 3.4.0 with flutter appplication, my probleme is that the prices of product is always on USD, Even when I change the country and the region  in my iPhone X, to show the prices I use product.priceString.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a sandbox tester in App Store Connect, you can define the App Store Country or Region for the tester - that will determine the locale of the `SKProduct`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding Revenuecat is an interface to GooglePlay and AppStore features.

I think you should define the price and related currencies in your app page on respective stores.

Revenuecat documentation:

- [Product definition for iOS](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/ios-products#setting-subscription-price)
- [Product definition for Android](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/android-products#create-an-in-app-purchase)

Additional resources towards that answer: [Google FAQ](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1169947?hl=en) and [Guide to multiple currencies](https://marketfinder.thinkwithgoogle.com/intl/en/guide/apps-in-multiple-currencies/#setting-prices-free-paid)

Comment: I have follow RevenueCat documentation, but it not working.